# Java/MySQL: Insert date gives "Unknown column 'date'" even though its there (Error 1054 (42s22))

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-error-1054

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I have a table like this:

```
mysql> describe mytable;
Field       Type       Null     Key      Default      Extra
-----------+----------+--------+--------+------------+---------------
id          int(11)    NO       PRI      NULL         auto_increment
foreignid   int(11)    NO       MUL      NULL
date        date       NO                '0000-00-00'
[some more columns]
```

I'm trying to insert values via a preparedStatement:

```
String insert = "insert into mytable (foreignid, date) values (?, ?)";
PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(insert);
pst.setInt(1, newForeignID);     //valid foreign key
pst.setDate(2, newDate);         //newDate is a proper java.sql.Date
pst.execute();
```

That should be fairly straightforward, yet I always get this error:

```
Unknown column 'date' in 'field list'
```

Any idea why that happens?

Answer (score 1):

date is a Keyword in mysql. You should escape or better rename it:

```
String insert = "insert into mytable (foreignid, `date`) values (?, ?)";
```

Comment: I'm always of the rename school of thought. I don't know why, but for some reason dates seem to be unique in that everyone wants to name the fields that hold them the data type. Whenever I see people thinking of adding such fields I always think/ask, "date of what?" birthdate? expiration date? start date? end date? anniversary? etc...

Comment: @mxgx use `\``, not `'`; the one under the tilde, not the one under the double quote.

Comment: I renamed the column and used these `\`` quotation marks, but I still get the error with the old column name `Unknown column 'date' in 'field list'`.

Comment: @mxgx Have you rebuild the Programm?

Comment: @Jens Yes, I recompiled the class and rebuild the entire project. Same thing happens if I restart the server and try to insert via Terminal, I still get `Unknown column \`date\` in \`field list\``, even though the column is now named \`testdate\`.

Comment: By the way, the SQL spec explicitly promises to never use a trailing underscore in a keyword. So that‘s a perfect way to easily avoid naming conflicts with a reserved word. I simple append an underscore to all table names, column names, index names, and such.

Comment: Ok, I've found the error. Apparently I had a trigger still referring to the old column name, after updating it everything worked fine. [This](https://www.psce.com/blog/2015/07/16/unobvious-unknown-column-in-field-list-error/) post brought me on the right track.